# moment js bug for certain dates. moment.year(x).week(y).endOf("week")

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am getting some weird output for certain dates for moment js.
It is only for the dates 1st, 2nd and 3rd of Jan 2022 otherwise it works as expected.
I would expect the same output regardless of the current date.

Any idea why this is occurring?

```
console.log('Test 2019', moment().year(2019).week(48).endOf("week"));
console.log('Test 2020', moment().year(2020).week(48).endOf("week"));
console.log('Test 2021', moment().year(2021).week(48).endOf("week"));
console.log('Test 2022', moment().year(2022).week(48).endOf("week"));
console.log('Test 2023', moment().year(2023).week(48).endOf("week"));

// With date of device set to the future 3/Jan/2022
Test 2019 Sun Dec 09 2018 23:59:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2020 Sun Dec 08 2019 23:59:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2021 Sun Dec 06 2020 23:59:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2022 Sun Dec 04 2022 23:59:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2023 Sun Dec 03 2023 23:59:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)

// With date of device set to the today 15/dec/2021
Test 2019 Sun Dec 08 2019 23:59:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2020 Sun Dec 06 2020 23:59:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2021 Sun Dec 05 2021 23:59:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2022 Sun Dec 04 2022 23:59:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2023 Sun Dec 03 2023 23:59:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
```

Updated test:

```
console.log('Test 2019 B', moment().year(2019));
console.log('Test 2020 B', moment().year(2020));
console.log('Test 2021 B', moment().year(2021));
console.log('Test 2022 B', moment().year(2022));
console.log('Test 2023 B', moment().year(2023));

// With date of device set to auto / today 15/dec/2021
Test 2019 B Sun Dec 15 2019 15:14:54 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2020 B Tue Dec 15 2020 15:14:54 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2021 B Wed Dec 15 2021 15:14:54 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2022 B Thu Dec 15 2022 15:14:54 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2023 B Fri Dec 15 2023 15:14:54 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)

// With date of device set to the future 3/Jan/2022
Test 2019 B Thu Jan 03 2019 15:21:48 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2020 B Fri Jan 03 2020 15:21:48 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2021 B Sun Jan 03 2021 15:21:48 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2022 B Mon Jan 03 2022 15:21:48 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2023 B Tue Jan 03 2023 15:21:48 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)

console.log('Test 2019 C', moment().year(2019).week(48));
console.log('Test 2020 C', moment().year(2020).week(48));
console.log('Test 2021 C', moment().year(2021).week(48));
console.log('Test 2022 C', moment().year(2022).week(48));
console.log('Test 2023 C', moment().year(2023).week(48));

// With date of device set to the future 3/Jan/2022
Test 2019 C Thu Dec 06 2018 15:26:35 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2020 C Fri Dec 06 2019 15:26:35 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2021 C Sun Dec 06 2020 15:26:35 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2022 C Mon Nov 28 2022 15:26:35 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Test 2023 C Tue Nov 28 2023 15:26:35 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
```

Comment: are you using the same device? I guess it is something about starting on Monday / Sunday issue with locale.

Comment: @Horst yes same device.  But the year is completely different and there is a gap of 2 years between 2021 and 2022.

Comment: Try using .format to output a string from the moment objects before logging them. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Updated the post with new tests.  It looks like I don't understand what .week() does.

Comment: Well, Moment is [no longer being maintained](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), but the [documentation for `week`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/) describes what it does pretty well.

Comment: @forgivenson .format() makes no difference.

Comment: Well it looks like a bug with moment js to me.  I have logged it.  Assuming there is no difference between putting my local clock forward and the real Jan 3 2022.  https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5960