# Moment not comparing weekly date correctly?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

here is the example. i have it always return true

```
const lastDiscountCode = moment(202352,"YYYYWW");
const currentWeek = moment().format("YYYYWW");
alert(moment(lastDiscountCode).isBefore(moment(currentWeek)));
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that [per the devs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), you should consider migrating off of momentjs. It's considered a legacy project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.format("YYYYWW")` on `lastDiscountCode` :

```js
const lastDiscountCode = moment(202352,"YYYYWW").format("YYYYWW");
const currentWeek = moment().format("YYYYWW");
console.log(moment(lastDiscountCode).isBefore(moment(currentWeek)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: use 202252 it should return true but its false

Comment: @MubashirSiddiqui what do you mean ? `202152` returns `true`. But `202252` is not before current week which is `202204`.

Comment: if i do it ike this 

const currentWeek = moment("2022-01-01T00:00:00+05:00").format("YYYYWW");

it give me 202252 why ?

Comment: `moment("2022-01-01T00:00:00+05:00").format("YYYYWW")` returns `202152` because "The calendar week 52 in year 2021 from Monday, 27.12.2021
to Sunday, 02.01.2022."

Comment: no it returns 202252 not 202152

Comment: It looks like we are facing something similar to the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70357522/16688813). The date of my device is set to 28/01/2022.

Answer (score 0):

In moment(202352, "YYYYWW").format("YYYYWW") what you enter inside the moment function takes the data and converts it into date format first, and then that date is formatted into 'YYYYWW'. So what you should be doing is enter a date inside the moment and then format it into 'YYYYWW'

```js
const lastDiscountCode = moment('2024-09-28').format("YYYYWW");
const currentWeek = moment().format("YYYYWW");
console.log(currentWeek);      // "202204"
console.log(lastDiscountCode); // "202439"
alert(moment(lastDiscountCode).isBefore(moment(currentWeek))); // false
```